# Plot series that cannot be sorted avoiding Highcharts error 15

Tags: highcharts

2nd EDITION:

I'm re-frasing the question in hope to be more clear.

I have a data series like:
[ [-3,30], [-2,40], [1,50], [3,60], [2,50], [-1,40], [-4,30] ]

I need Highcharts to plot it in a graphic like a line. Highcharts gives the error 15 because the series is not sorted.

Problem is that the series cannot be sorted because it would falsify the data output. The examples on the pictures and the fiddle show the expected result and what happens if the series get sorted (a blurred plot):

- [Result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I2RK.png)
- [Result from sorting data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdF5g.png)
- fiddle plot in my comment (can't attach the link here)

I tried spline and area but both give the error 15.

I tried polygon that avoids the error 15 but it plots a filled area and I cannot get only the borders.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Here is an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/pfddg2je/12/
(implemented with area but you may change the type to see the effects of the sorting on other graph types)

Comment: I can't visualize what you want vs what is being plotted in the fiddle.  Can you add an image of what you want the results to look like?

Comment: Let us know what is incorret in your fiddle and supply a mockup, how it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Just got a solution from the Highcharts forum, by Izothep (big thanks for him):

```
with scatter http://jsfiddle.net/izothep/pfddg2je/17/
with polygon http://jsfiddle.net/izothep/45v6xefb/1/
```

Sorry but I don't have the rights yet to post the fiddle links directly.

If you have more than one series you can, for instance, loop through the Highcharts.getOptions().colors[ i ], were i is the series number, and set it on the lineColor and the color on the called 'fake' on the presented solutions.